# Jealous Husband Puzzle A* heuristic function

Tags: java, search, a-star

Could anyone offer some help with the heuristic function for the following problem, where the cost is the total weight carried? I am able to find a good solution (cost: 81), but not the optimal one (cost: 70).

The problem:

- Three couples (A, B and C) are trying to get across a river.
- The raft can hold a maximum of 2 people.
- There must be at least one person in the raft for it to move.
- In any location (i.e. river bank or raft), a husband will be jealous
  if his wife is in the presence of another man and he himself is not
  there.
- In the first couple the husband and the wife weigh 10 units each, the
  second pair weighs 5 units each and the third weighs 1 each.

The optimal solution is as follows (I need to develop this heuristic function), where X is the raft, uppercase letters are husbands, lowercase letters are wives:

```
Initial state:

------
AaBbCcX

Goal state:

AaBbCcX
------

Node explored: 93 Cost: 70.0

------
AaBbCcX

SOUTH->NORTH: ac (Cost: 11.0)
acX
------
ABbC

NORTH->SOUTH: c (Cost: 1.0)
a
------
ABbCcX

SOUTH->NORTH: bc (Cost: 6.0)
abcX
------
ABC

NORTH->SOUTH: b (Cost: 5.0)
ac
------
ABbCX

SOUTH->NORTH: AC (Cost: 11.0)
AaCcX
------
Bb

NORTH->SOUTH: Cc (Cost: 2.0)
Aa
------
BbCcX

SOUTH->NORTH: BC (Cost: 6.0)
AaBCX
------
bc

NORTH->SOUTH: a (Cost: 10.0)
ABC
------
abcX

SOUTH->NORTH: ab (Cost: 15.0)
AaBbCX
------
c

NORTH->SOUTH: C (Cost: 1.0)
AaBb
------
CcX

SOUTH->NORTH: Cc (Cost: 2.0)
AaBbCcX
------
```

So far I've managed to come up with two functions, which still hiccup somewhere.

The first one calculates the score (the lower the score the more promising the node is) based on how much weight still needs to cross the river, which manages to achieve the cost of 89 and makes the same steps as the optimal solution in the beginning and the end:

```
/**
 * Calculate the total weight of all couples. This will be used to calculate how far the given state is from the
 * goal state.
 */
private Problem calculateTotalWeight() {
    People[] banks = new People[]{this.goalState.getNorthBank(), this.goalState.getSouthBank()};

    for (People i : banks) {
        this.weightTotal += i.getCumulativeWeight();
    }

    return this;
}

/**
 * The heuristic evaluation function. The score is determined by subtracting the cumulative weight of people on the
 * goal state bank from the total weight of all people, i.e. the more people are on the goal bank, the closer we are
 * to the goal.
 *
 * @param state The evaluated state
 */
public float heuristicDistanceFromGoal(State state) {
    // If we're moving from the south bank to the north, do calculations on the north bank and vice-versa.
    People bank = RunMe.getGoalBank() == Bank.NORTH ? state.getNorthBank() : state.getSouthBank();

    return this.weightTotal - bank.getCumulativeWeight();
}


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT]


Moving W1, W3 (total weight: 11.0) to the North bank
 W1 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W2


Moving W1 (weight: 1.0) to the South bank
 W3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W1 W2 [RAFT]


Moving W1, W2 (total weight: 6.0) to the North bank
 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3


Moving W1 (weight: 1.0) to the South bank
 W2 W3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W1 [RAFT]


Moving H2, H3 (total weight: 15.0) to the North bank
 H2 H3 W2 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 W1


Moving H2, W2 (total weight: 10.0) to the South bank
 H3 W3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 W1 W2 [RAFT]


Moving H1, H2 (total weight: 6.0) to the North bank
 H1 H2 H3 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W1 W2


Moving W3 (weight: 10.0) to the South bank
 H1 H2 H3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT]


Moving W2, W3 (total weight: 15.0) to the North bank
 H1 H2 H3 W2 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W1


Moving H1 (weight: 1.0) to the South bank
 H2 H3 W2 W3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 W1 [RAFT]


Moving H1, W1 (total weight: 2.0) to the North bank
 H1 H2 H3 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Nodes visited: 56
Cost: 89.0

Raft capacity: 2
Number of couples: 3, total weight: 32.0
```

The second one calculates its score based on how much weight gets on the raft for each transfer:

```
/**
 * Calculates the weight of people that got moved between the states
 *
 * @param otherState The state we're comparing with
 */
public double calculateWeightDiff(State otherState) {
    return Math.abs(this.northBank.getCumulativeWeight() - otherState.getNorthBank().getCumulativeWeight());
}

/**
 * The heuristic evaluation function. The score is equal to the cumulative weight of the people moved.
 *
 * @param node The evaluated node
 */
public double heuristicWeightMoved(Node node) {
    // node is the state after the couples move to either bank.
    // parentState is the previous state or the startState if this is our first action
    Node parentNode = node.parent;
    State parentState = (State) (parentNode != null ? parentNode.state : this.startState);

    return ((State) node.state).calculateWeightDiff(parentState);
}



~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT]


Moving H1, W1 (total weight: 2.0) to the North bank
 H1 W1 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H2 H3 W2 W3


Moving H1 (weight: 1.0) to the South bank
 W1 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W2 W3 [RAFT]


Moving W2, W3 (total weight: 15.0) to the North bank
 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3


Moving W2 (weight: 5.0) to the South bank
 W1 W3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 H3 W2 [RAFT]


Moving H1, H3 (total weight: 11.0) to the North bank
 H1 H3 W1 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H2 W2


Moving H1, W1 (total weight: 2.0) to the South bank
 H3 W3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 H1 H2 W1 W2 [RAFT]


Moving H1, H2 (total weight: 6.0) to the North bank
 H1 H2 H3 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W1 W2


Moving W3 (weight: 10.0) to the South bank
 H1 H2 H3 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT]


Moving W1, W2 (total weight: 6.0) to the North bank
 H1 H2 H3 W1 W2 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W3


Moving W1 (weight: 1.0) to the South bank
 H1 H2 H3 W2 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 W1 W3 [RAFT]


Moving W1, W3 (total weight: 11.0) to the North bank
 H1 H2 H3 W1 W2 W3 [RAFT] 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Nodes visited: 96
Cost: 81.0
```

Given how close the first function's steps are to the optimal path, I am sure it's very close and just needs a minor change. As this is a fairly classic puzzle, has anyone managed to find the optimal heuristic function for it?

Comment: I think your question would fit better on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: The heuristik in A* must be a lower bound of the expected cost. The algorithm will then always find the optimal solution. Different functions will only influence how fast the solution is found. The trivial lower bound (constantly 0) will also work but will lead to the longest runtime.
If this is not the case for you, there is something wrong with the implementation.

Comment: @dguay Not really. Whilst it is in a somewhat grey area, CodeReview is about taking working code and making it better (be that direct performance, or readability of the code, or structure or whatever). In this case, where the OP is specifically asking for a mathematically optimal function, that would fall outside the scope of CR. If they wanted feedback on their code as-is (such as how to compute their function faster/more efficiently), then it would probably be within CR's scope.